# Running Meteor on windows gives "You're not in a Meteor project directory" after upgrade to Meteor.js 1.3

Tags: javascript, meteor

My Meteor project has been running just fine in my windows development environment until the @1.3 release updated. Suddenly, it became unable to identify my existing meteor project directory as a Meteor project directory, giving the message
    You're not in a Meteor project directory

I can create new meteor projects, which seem to work fine, but I cannot get my existing project to run after the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to updated meteor\release

It said

```
METEOR@1.2.1
```

I changed it to

```
METEOR@1.3
```

And everything started to work again.

Comment: I figured it out after comparing the existing project's \.meteor\ directory to a newly created project's.

Comment: It has happened again with the Meteor@1.3.1 release. When a meteor project that used to work stops, run
`meteor --version`
And ensure that your \.meteor\release matches the version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing the .meteor/packages file. Once restored meteor started running app again.